# php use switch within echo statement

Tags: php, switch-statement, echo

I need to use a statement like switch within echo statement

I found a way for this ,but i think this is not the best way for this
when we want to use IF inside echo,write some thing like:

```
echo ((condition)?'print this if condition is True':'print this if condition is False');
```

we could use this method for a way like switch:

```
echo ((case1)?'case 1 result':((case2)?'case2 result':((case3)?'case3 result':'default result')));
```

are you know a better way for this?

Comment: what about making it countrary - put echo within case?

Comment: Ternary operator as you have in the first example is the best way to do it in an echo. Otherwise you need to build your html string in a switch statement and echo out the result.

Comment: I think you should use `switch` or series of `if` statements. Chained ternary operators are very hard to read.

Comment: To be able to think with you, what practical use do you have in mind?

Answer (score 1):

Your example is called ternary operators its basically short hand for an if statement.

So in your second example you're just doing a load of chained if then else's

You're far better off doing something like this

```
    switch ($type)) {
    case "txt":
         $output = "images/doctypes/icon_txt.gif";
    break;
    case "doc":
         $output = "images/doctypes/icon_doc.gif";
    break;
    case "docx":
         $output = "images/doctypes/icon_doc.gif";
    break;
    case "pdf":
         $output = "images/doctypes/icon_pdf.gif";
    break;
    case "xls":
         $output = "images/doctypes/icon_xls.gif";
    break;
    case "xlsx":
         $output = "images/doctypes/icon_xls.gif";
    break;
    case "ppt":
         $output = "images/doctypes/icon_ppt.gif";
    break;
    case "pptx":
         $output = "images/doctypes/icon_txt.gif";
    break;
    case "rtf":
         $output = "images/doctypes/icon_txt.gif";
    break;
    case "zip":
         $output = "images/doctypes/icon_zip.gif";
    break;
    case "rar":
         $output = "images/doctypes/icon_zip.gif";
    break;
    case "mdb":
         $output = "images/doctypes/mdb.gif";
    break;
    default:
         $output = "images/doctypes/icon_generic.gif";
    };

echo $output;
```

Comment: yikes! what about using an *array* for this? Or, *at least*, grouping similar values?

Comment: I could do but I don't mostly because its grown over time in the copy/paste example there was only 2-3 things initially but I also don't echo out like that either.  For his usage though he wanted a switch case option of ternary this is an example of that.  Yes abit silly as you pointed out but its doing exactly what he wanted in the question

Comment: While your example isn't great the point you're making is sensible, keep the logic outside of the echo statements.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. If I understand correctly, you want to know the how-maniest condition was the first successful one?

I just thought this up... See if it fits you.

Just replace the false/true with your conditions.

```
$i = 0;
++$i AND false OR // 1
++$i AND false OR // 2
++$i AND false OR // 3
++$i AND true  OR // 4 (here we go)
++$i AND false OR // 5
++$i AND true  OR // 6 (ignored)
++$i AND false OR // 7
$i = 0;           // 0

echo "case" . $i . " result"; // echoes 'case4 result'
```

**EDIT:**
Here is another approach with the same technique.
But in stead of a counter, you can give your own on-success string.
Remember to just replace the false/true with your conditions.

```
function dostuff($str) { echo $str; return true;}

false AND dostuff('string1') OR
false AND dostuff('string2') OR
false AND dostuff('string3') OR
true  AND dostuff('string4') OR // echoes 'string4'
false AND dostuff('string5') OR
true  AND dostuff('string6') OR // ignored
false AND dostuff('string7');
```